# Set environment variables when activating python virtual environment in windows

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-venv

I want to be able to set up environment variables in my virtual environment so that they are available in my code when I activate the virtual environment. I make my virtual enviornments with venv.  I'm working on a Windows machine with VS-code.

What I already tried, but didn't work.

1. Adding the vars to end of the activate.bat file like this:

```sh
set CLIENT_SECRET="MYSECRET"
```

2. Adding the vars to the end of the Activate.ps1 file like this:

```
$CLIENT_SECRET="MYSECRET"
```

3. Adding the vars to the end of the activate file like this:

```
export CLIENT_SECRET="MYSECRET"
```

I found a lot related to my topic, but none working for me. What to do?

Comment: It's not having difficulties finding my environment, it's just not loading the vars. I used to work in Pycharm, which I really like, but changed to VS Code since it has a lot of free plugins/supports more languages compared to the Community Version of Pycharm. Maybe, it's time to get out the wallet... :)

Comment: If you liked PyCharm (I do as well), but you need broad support for many languages, you could consider IntelliJ - I am curious what languages you think PyCharm does not support as an editor, that VSCode would though. Often the answer is 'there is a plugin for that'. But IntelliJ will have you covered for full-featured support of most languages - as will other similar platforms like Visual Studio for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to setup your development environment in VSCode you can simply add `.env` file with all secrets defined in project root directory. More details in [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file)

Comment: I gave this a shot, but also this does not seem to work. I placed a file named dev.env in my project root folder with the following var assignment `CLIENT_SECRET=MYSECRET`

Comment: How are you running your script? If you want to load environment automatically you need to use VSCode debugger with its configuration. By default just hit `F5` or Debug -> Start Debugging, on your python file and VSCode will load environment from `.dev` file.

Comment: I tried in debug mode, but also direct in my terminal. Maybe I'm calling the vars the wrong way, how should I call them in my code?

Comment: Python: 'os.environ.get("CLIENT_SECRET")'

Comment: If you name your environment definition file something other than `.env` you will need to set the appropriate setting to point to the file such as the [`"python.envFile"` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file).

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick, it works both in the Python Interactive as in Debugging mode. It only doesn't work when right clicking the file and select the "Run Python File in Terminal" option. Guess I won't be using that anymore. Marked as solved, thx!

Answer (score 2):

Your first solution

`set CLIENT_SECRET=MYSECRET`

in `activate.bat`should work, when using Command Prompt in the terminal as Default Shell.

You can omit the quotes unless they are part of your envirionment variable.

You can verify, if the environment variable is set with:

`echo %CLIENT_SECRET%` in the terminal in VS-Code.

Comment: Ok, it indeed works. However, it only works when i'm running it in Python Interactive and not when I'm running it in the terminal. Also, your suggested code to echo the var is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

go to endowment variable folder enter Script folder now activate with cmd

Answer (score 0):

use set in CMD teminal

use env: in powershell

Answer (score 0):

The default Terminal that popped up for me in VS Code was the PowerShell, which I didn't realize at first. I had to use:

**To write the env variable**

```
$Env:MYAPP_DB_USER = "myapp_user"
```

**To read the env variable**

```
$Env:MYAPP_DB_USER
```

NB: '$' in front is part of the command. 'MYAPP_DB_USER' is the Key and 'myapp_user' is the Value
I don't want to keep the passwords and keys as part of the code (including .env file) and have it pushed to the git repo and the server.

Ref: [Microsoft PowerShell - Env variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.4)